# Selenium Click Does not work, but Manual Click works

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

my code currently is:

```
driver.get("http://w2.leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/index/index.jsp")
window1 = driver.window_handles[0]
facility_basic_version = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div")
facility_basic_version.click()

# deselect selected captcha
window2 = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window2)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="kbkey button red_selected sel"]'))).click() 

#Solve Captcha here

#
#
#

# Click continue at specific time
while len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="kbkey button red_selected sel"]')) < 4:
    print('captcha not done')

pyautogui.moveTo(634, 586, 0.5, pyautogui.easeInQuad)
time.sleep(0.3)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.mouseUp()
print('captcha done')
time.sleep(100)
```

I have a section to solve captcha, but since I haven't implemented that part yet, for testing purposes I am still solving captcha manually.

The problem: after solving captcha, I want to click the continue button. However, if try to find the element, then click on button, I would be met with an error (site knows I am using automation). I tried just starting up chromedriver, doing all the steps the bot would do manually and click the continue button manually, and the site would allow me to continue to next page. Hence, I tried using pyautogui to simulate mouse movement but still site gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

A captcha is by definition designed to prevent automation, so I'm not surprised this does not work.
You might still be able to find a workaround and this might help: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-handle-captcha-in-selenium

Comment: my problem is not with the captcha, for testing purposes I am solving the captcha manually. What is happening is I am getting blocked by the site if I use any find.element in selenium.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what blocked means? Do you get an error? Does it time out?

Comment: the site redirects me to a page that says error. If you use my code u can reproduce the problem. U just need to solve the captcha and selenium will click the continue button for you. This will show you the error page. However, if you comment out all the find.element for the 2nd window, and solve captcha manually and click continue, site continues as expected.